# ajax coffeescript request-- get param

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I'm using rails to build a demo app, and I have a bunch of rows of data that have buttons attached. Clicking the button sends a `delete` request to the controller, and when it returns success I want to use jQuery to delete the row from the page.

The recommended coffescript for the ajax request works fine-- but I'm wondering how to access the sent params in the request:

```
$("a[data-remote]").on "ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
if data.status == 'success' 
    console.dir(data) // stuff is printed, results are returned
    // do stuff
```

So I have the message back from the controller that the function completed, and I want to update a page element by the ID of the button clicked.

But unless I modify the data sent back to include the data that was originally sent in the `GET` or `delete` request (which seems unnecessary and inefficient) I don't know how to access to ID of the original element that was sent in the first place!

How can I access the ID sent in the original request?

Comment: Why not hook up the AJAX calls by hand so that you can easily hook up `success` handlers rather than messing around with `ajax:success` events?

Comment: @muistooshort-- good point. I'm just trying to get my head around the "rails way" so I'm doing what's recommended in tutorials.

Comment: Have you looked at what `this` is in your callback? I don't use any of that stuff so I don't know what it would be.

Comment: good call mu-- `this` at least returns the anchor element, so I can grab the id from that. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Don't forget to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

A pure Rails way to do it is to include a `.js.erb` file in your `views` dir:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
respond_to :html, :js

def action
   @id = params[:var][:id]
   respond_with @id
end

#app/views/controller/action.js.erb
alert("<%=j @id %>");
```

---

If you'd like to use the `ajax:success` callback, you'd be best doing something like this:

```
#app/views/controller/view.html.erb
<%= link_to "link", link_path, remote: true, data: { type: "json" } %>

#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
def action
   @message = { id: params[:var][:id], message: "message" }
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @message.to_json }
   end
end

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$("a[data-remote]").on "ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    var info = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(info.message);
```